# How to access sequences defined in an Oracle database for id generation with the Sequence Generator Annotation

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, toad

I am trying to set up table entities with primary key id's generated from sequences I previously defined and used in an Oracle DB.

I am trying to use the Sequence Generator and Generated Value annotations but they don't seem to work quite right for me. I'm unsure what I am missing/doing wrong.

```java
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(Strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", sequenceName = "id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private long id;
```

This does not seem to work. Any advice on how to solve this problem, or a usable workaround, would be appreciated. This uses an Oracle 11 DB and JPA 2.

Comment: what's the error msg?

Comment: @QingfeiYuan its a uniqueness constraint error. It is not actually assigning the next value of the sequence as the id.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, working with JPA 2.0, of how to get an `id` from an Oracle sequence.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_JPA_ID_GENERATOR")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_JPA_ID_GENERATOR", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "MY_ORACLE_SEQUENCE_NAME")
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Long ID;
```